# Review colorification issues

Tags: discussion

When I look to my reviews, if I have Reviews pending, could you turn 'Review' green, or maybe beige? This would be very helpful of you.

Comment: Something similar is in effect once you get to (I believe) 2k or 3k rep; it's a little box with the number of pending reviews next to the "review" link.

Comment: @apnorton The general review count is shown to 10K users. 2K users  get an indicator of suggested edits.

Comment: @2mkgz Hm. It's amazing how quickly I got used to this counter, then. :)